# Set background for alaska and hawaii using choroplethr

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth, choroplethr

I am using the [choroplethr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/index.html) package to create a heatmap, but I am not able to set the opacity for alaska and hawaii. 
[image]

Code:

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(choroplethr)
  library(choroplethrMaps)

  data = data.frame(region=c(1001, 1003), value=c(-100,100))
  choro = CountyChoropleth$new(data)
  choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_gradient2("",
                                            low="red",
                                            high="green",
                                            na.value="white")
  choro$set_num_colors(1)
  plot = choro$render() + 
    theme(
          legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
          strip.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
          legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)
    )
  ggsave(plot=plot,
         filename=paste0("~/counties.png"),
         bg="transparent")
```

Comment: I'd file an issue on the gh repo since this is a problem with the way the map is created.  i can work up an alternate example with my [`albersusa`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/albersusa) package if desired.